# make_unique cannot access private constructor in static member

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

My class has the following structure:

```cpp
class S {
  public:
    S() {}
};

class T {
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<S> a;
    T(S);

  public:
    static std::unique_ptr<T> make_item() {
        std::unique_ptr<S> s_instance = std::make_unique<S>();
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::move(s_instance));
    }
};
```

However, when I try to make a unique_ptr in the make_item, it sees the constructor as private.

Is there a way to allow the use of the private constructor in a static member function of the class itself? Because one member is a unique_ptr to S (a rather heavy object), we wish not to use a copy.

Comment: I second the duplicate proposition, but `std::make_unique` can be replaced with `std::unique_ptr<X>(new X);` without any performance loss, so the tricks from that question are not required.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen But that's not exception safe! A factory pattern is the better approach, if this constraint is relevant.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen By "without any performance loss" you mean not considering the extra allocation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As proposed by yksisarvinen in the comments, a way to solve this is to just replace `make_unique<T>` by `std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(S))`.

```cpp
class S {
  public:
    S() {}
};
class T {
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<S> a;
    T(S);

  public:
    static std::unique_ptr<T> make_item() {
        // Create S
        std::unique_ptr<S> s_instance = std::make_unique<S>();
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(s_instance));
    }
};
```

Comment: answering your own question is fine, but note that the question is a bit unclear. I suggest you to add the missing `;`, the declaration of `S` and the error message, so others can actually see the problem

Comment: So what is the benefit of using std::make_unique here? We use if for its safety which is not provided by 'new'. I think a better answer could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995599/make-unique-doesnt-compile-for-creating-a-singleton-instance

Comment: @AshkanVZ is correct, the other answer he referred to is better. The accepted answer here is not exception-safe and could potentially leak.

Comment: @Dalzhim no, this will not leak as currently presented. There is a point to be made about exception safety around `make_unique` in the case where multiple `unique_ptr`s are initialised within the same expression but it doesn’t apply to this particular example.

Comment: @xcvii I had to test it to convince myself : https://godbolt.org/z/454f7Gar4 but you are correct, the leak may happen if multiple new subexpressions occur within the same expression, but it doesn't happen in this specific example.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to either declare make_unique and its internal helpers (if any) a friend function, which make the code non-portable (as said here: [How to make std::make_unique a friend of my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905030/how-to-make-stdmake-unique-a-friend-of-my-class))

Or make the constructor public but add a private element to its arguments, for example:

```cpp
class S {
  public:
    S() {}
};

class T {
  private:
    struct Private
    { 
      friend T;
      private:
        explicit Private() = default; 
    };

    std::unique_ptr<S> a;

  public:
    T(S s, Private);

    static std::unique_ptr<T> make_item() {
        auto s_instance = std::make_unique<S>();
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::move(s_instance), Private());
    }
};
```

Comment: You can use the pass key idiom to avoid letting just anyone make_unique on your type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29897660/874660

Comment: Thanks for introducing the term "Passkey Idiom", I didn't know the term. Do I understand correctly? Is it the generic idea of the answer I provided?

Comment: No, the problem with making make_unique a friend is that then anyone can make_unique so it’s as good as a public c’tor more or less. With the pass key idiom, you have a public c’tor but one of the arguments is of a type that only your class can create so that c’tor is as good as private as far as your API but you can allow others (like make_unique) to call it by passing make_unique an instance of the passkey class.